# MUI Select label not hiding properly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a MUI Select which I want to hide the label, but it's not working:

```
    <FormControl fullWidth>
      <Select
        value={selectedEntry}
        onChange={(e) => handleSelectEntry(e.target.value)}
        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'Without label' }}
      >
        {dropDownList?.map((entry) => (
          <MenuItem key={entry.key} value={entry.key}>{entry.value}</MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
```

It display this: output [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG16y.png)

Comment: have you added `label` in your component. Looks like if you remove that it will work

Comment: Nope, I dont have label in my component @ShubhamVerma

Comment: I have tried . See this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/multipleselectplaceholder-material-demo-forked-ikiqi?file=/demo.js:1529-1554

Answer (score 2):

You can set the [`displayEmpty` prop of Select](https://mui.com/api/select/), if true, a value is displayed even if no items are selected.
In order to display a meaningful value, a function can be passed to the `renderValue` prop which returns the value to be displayed when no items are selected. But you can don't provide any `renderValue` and no "label" (actually its more like a default displayed value) will be shown.

Empty select:

```
<Select
  value={selectedEntry}
  displayEmpty
  onChange={(e) => handleSelectEntry(e.target.value)}
>
```

Select with default displayed value:

```
<Select
  value={selectedEntry}
  displayEmpty
  onChange={(e) => handleSelectEntry(e.target.value)}
  renderValue={value => value || 'there\'s nothing selected'}
>
```

Comment: Nice! it works!